# pointer to other class (boost::variate_generator) not work

Tags: c++, boost, random

I'm trying to generate random numbers using *boost/random.hpp*, I'd like to fix the seed at initialization, and call *getRandom()* to generate random numbers according to the seed. But this code doesn't work:

```
class A 
{
public:
    A() 
    {
        unsigned long seed =12411;
        boost::mt19937 rng(seed);
        boost::normal_distribution<> norm(0.0, 1.0);  
        boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,
                                 boost::normal_distribution<> > 
        randNorm(rng, norm);
        randPtr = &randNorm;
        //(*randPtr)();
        std::cout << (*randPtr)() << std::endl;
    }
    double getRandom() 
    {
        return (*randPtr)();
    }        
private:
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,
                             boost::normal_distribution<> >* 
    randPtr;

};
int main() {
    A a;
    std::cout << a.getRandom() << std::endl;
}
```

For the above code, it can compile, will print one random number (called in the constructor), then *Segmentation fault: 11*. So the pointer randPtr only works inside the constructor. Could anyone give me any suggestion on this? Thank you!

Comment: Why are pointers involved at all?

Comment: Hi @Hurkyl, I was trying to use a boost::variate_generator<> object as a private member, but I cannot instantialize this object inside the body of A's constructor, so I give up then later

Comment: Ah, an XY problem; you should ask another question about your original problem: how to initialize an object when you need to do something complicated to set it up. That has an answer worth knowing!

Comment: Hi @Hurkyl, yes, I would like to know how to do that. I adopted Tomasz's suggestion by making both objects living longer, now it works, that's a good solution but doesn't seem to be a clever way considering what I initially want to do...

Answer (score 0):

`randNorm` is a local variable (destroyed at end of destructor), and you use it after destruction.
If you want a pointer, write:

`randPtr = new boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::normal_distribution<> >(rng, norm);`

However, from `&` in type you can guess that your distribution uses reference to pseudo-random number generator, so you'll have to make it live longer too.

In general - usage of `unique_ptr` (or `scoped_ptr` if you prefer `boost` or don't have access to C++11) would be better. You can also use these objects as fields, since you don't use them polymorphically.

Comment: I see, the pointer is pointing to something which is local... Thank you!